# How to make recursive call (getTotalFiles) thread-safe?

Tags: java

Im making a recursive file checking, the problem is i cant have counter inside the method itself, so that i declared it outside. But the problem is, this isnt thread safe.

```
private int countFiles = 0;
private int getTotalFiles(String path) {

    File file = new File(path);
    File listFile[] = file.listFiles();

    for (File f : listFile) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            countFiles++;
        }
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            getTotalFiles(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    return countFiles;
}
```

Class variable countFiles is not thread safe. How to make this thread safe ?

Comment: Hm, have you used or looked up synchronization yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a field, just add the result of the recursive call to `countFiles`.

```
private int getTotalFiles(String path) {
    //...
    if (f.isFile()) {
        countFiles++;
    }
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        countFiles += getTotalFiles(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, the deep count of files in a directory is the sum of the files in the directory plus the deep count of each directory in the directory.

Comment: yes, you need to return the result of the recursion back, it solves the problem,.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any clear reason why countFiles should be a class level variable here. The code can be made thread safe by making countFiles a local variable, which is anyhow returned by the method.